# printing after splitting a line of text at delimiters

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am having trouble printing this. When I requested the user to insert an `int` it worked, but when attempting to switch it over to a `char` input it got screwy and won't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char delim[2] = ",";
    char *token;
    int j = 0;
    char *hh;
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];

    ptr_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    char *pt[] = { "H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na" };

    printf("what element do you want(Use atomic number)");
    scanf("%s", &hh);

    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        if (hh == pt[j]) {
            fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file);
            token = strtok(buf, delim);
            while (token != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
            break;
        } else {
            fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file);
            continue;
        }
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major problem here is, you are passing `scanf()` the address of an uninitialized pointer `hh`. `scanf` invokes undefined behavior trying to store the word at that address.

You should make `hh` an array, like `char hh[8] = {0};` and use `scanf()` this way:

```
 scanf("%7s", hh);  // to avoid buffer overflow
```

That said,

- `if(hh == pt[j])` is not the way to compare *strings*. You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to do that, and write `if (strcmp(hh, pt[j]) == 0)`.
- you should also check the return value of `scanf()` to verify if input was correctly converted.

Comment: So How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
char  *hh;
//...
scanf("%s", &hh);
```

it is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to `hh` uninitialized: it is pointing to garbage. 
Furthermore `"%s"` format specifier wants `char *` as passed parameter: you are passing `char **`

should be

```
char  *hh = malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN);
if (hh != NULL)
{
   //...
   scanf("%s", hh);
}
free(hh);
```

or simply

```
char  hh[MAX_STRING_LEN] = {0};
//...
scanf("%s", hh);
```

Into both examples `MAX_STRING_LEN` expresses the maximum accepted length of string + 1 for null terminator.

---

Using [c](/questions/tagged/c) you cannot compare strings using logical operator `==`, so the code

```
if(hh == pt[j])
```

is comparing addresses not the strings.
You can use [strcmp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) to do that.

Comment: I tried and was give an error.error: 'MAX_STRING_LEN' undeclared (first use in this function)                                                                                                                                                      
         char  hh[MAX_STRING_LEN] = {0};

Comment: @christian MAX_STRING_LEN was just an indicator that you should put the maximum string length you'd need.

Comment: It would be nice if `scanf` had semantics that resemble `printf`... unfortunately, `scanf("%*s", MAX_STRING_LEN-1, hh);` will just parse a word and discard it.  The `*` means *do not store*.  The only way to specify a maximum number of characters to store is with an explicit number in the format string.

Comment: You should still protect the destination by hardcoding some size.  It is ugly but safe.

Comment: @chqrlie I'd use fgets ;)

Comment: Sure, I'd use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.  `fgets()` is not a direct replacement for `scanf("%s"...)`.  Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` produces unexpected results, due to pending linefeeds...